# List as a property of linq query result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two classes:

```
class Person 
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}
class Phone
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And two collections:

```
List<Person> Persons;
List<Phone> Phones;
```

I would like to join them using linq and get as a result list of Result objects:

```
class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

How to implement this in linq?

Answer (score 4):

```
var resultList = 
from person in Persons
select new Result
{
    Name = person.Name,
    Numbers = 
    (
        from phone in Phones 
        where phone.PersonId == person.PersonId 
        select phone.Number
    ).ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join function of Linq

```
var joinedList = from c in Persons
                 join p in Phones p on p.PersonId equals c.PersonId
                 select new {Persons = c, Phones = p};
```

Update :

Seems like it must be returned as Result. Here we go.

```
var results = Persons.Select(c => new Result
              {
                  Name = c.Name, 
                  Numbers = Phones.Where(p=>p.PersonId == c.PersonId)
                                  .Select(n=>n.Number).ToList()
              });
```

Comment: It's not what the OP asked for. People can have multiple phone numbers, and he wants a list of his `Result` class. (i made the same mistake).

Comment: Wow, forget to read 3 words and you get CHOPPED! Anyways, updated to include a correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all phone numbers point to a single existing person this would work:

```
var results = Phones.GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
                    .Select(g => new Result()
{
    Name = Persons.Single(x => x.PersonId == g.Key).Name,
    Numbers = g.Select(x => x.Number).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty similar to Mike...

```
var resultList = from person in persons
select new Result
{
    Name = person.Name, 
    Numbers = phones
        .Where(x => x.PersonId == person.PersonId)
        .Select(x => x.Number)
        .ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure [Method Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx):

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();   /*Populate the list however you wish*/
List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();     /*Populate the list however you wish*/

List<Result> results = people
    .Select(singlePerson => new Result 
    { 
        Name = singlePerson.Name, 
        Numbers = phones
            .Where(singlePhone => singlePhone.PersonId.Equals(singlePerson.PersonId))
            .Select(singlePhone => singlePhone.Number)
            .ToList() 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I wouldn't just join the 2 collections by adding phone items to persons. Depending on what you're trying to achieve I would use an interface to specify the 2 classes have something in common.

But the other solutions work as well it just might not be the right solution depending on your problem.